# HTML Linking to a Work Item in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2012

I'm creating a custom report with the TFS 2012 Warehouse displaying some information about work items. I'd like to put a link on the work item elements in the report which takes the user to the work item in the team portal. Is it possible to directly link to a work item in the fancy new team portal. (not the sharepoint team web access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - just create a link in the following format:

```
http://tfsServer:8080/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_workitems/edit/123
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found the syntax was different. The following worked for me:

```
http://<TfsServer>:8080/tfs/<Collection>/<ProjectName>/_workitems#_a=edit&id=<TfsID>
```

Just modify `<TfsServer>`, `<Collection>`, `<ProjectName>` and the `<TfsID>` as you need it.

For example:

```
http://myServer:8080/tfs/myCollection/myProject/_workitems#_a=edit&id=123
```